# If $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n = \infty$ then also $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt s_n = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

From the definition of diverging sequences we have that

$ \forall M>0 \ \exists N $ such that $n>N \implies s_n >M $

From the first limit, we know that such an N exists since we assumed that the limit diverges. Now if I take $N' = N^2$ for the limit I want to prove, will it suffice?
If I am attacking this problem the wrong way, please suggest some other way.

Thank you.

Comment: Not at all. You are doing fine.

Comment: Thank you professor @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: You've to replace $M$ by $M^2$, not $N$ by $N^2$.

Comment: Tomath is right. Replacing $N$ with $N^2$ tells you nothing about how $\sqrt{s_n}$ compares with $M$. For instance, set $s_n=n\left(1+\frac{\sin n}{2}\right)$, $M=5$ and $N=5.96$. Even though $n>N\Rightarrow s_n>M$, we **don't** have $n>N^2\Rightarrow \sqrt{s_n}>M$. In fact, at $n=36>N^2$, we have $\sqrt{s_n}<M$. The right way to go about the proof is with $M\mapsto M^2$.

Comment: I believe you miss a crucial $\color{red}{+}$ sign, since we are allowed to say that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} n(-1)^n = \infty$ (meaning that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left|n(-1)^n\right|=+\infty$) but $\sqrt{s_n}$, in this case, is not always defined.

Comment: Also, according to different conventions, "$\{s_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is divergent" is not always equivalent to "$\lim_{n\to +\infty}s_n = +\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to +\infty}s_n = -\infty$".

Comment: @Tomath thank you for your comment. My thinking was that if we have to be past N for s_n > M , so we have to get past N^2 for \sqrt(s_n) > M. But now it just doens't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt s_n = \infty$. Fix $M>0$ arbitrarily.
Then, as $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n = \infty$, so there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_n>M^2$ for all $n\geq n_0$, which gives $\sqrt s_n>M$ for all $n\geq n_0.$
Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt s_n = \infty$

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt s_n = L<\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sqrt s_n\cdot \sqrt s_n)$ exists and is equal to $(\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt s_n)\cdot (\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt s_n)=L^2$, which is a contradiction.